# "Oh! It's a scorpion." - Which option when using reported speech?

Tags: exam-questions, reported-speech

> Mother said, "Oh! It's a scorpion. Don't go near it, children."

This is from a multiple-choice question with 4 options I have to choose the 'best' from them. The other two options were completely wrong so I didn't write them, its just these two options which are confusing me. What should be the indirect form of above given sentence?

> 1. *Mother exclaimed with disgust that it was a scorpion and told the children not to go near it.*
> 2. *Mother exclaimed with disgust that, that was a scorpion and told the children not to go near that.*

In indirect form just like we change *yesterday* to *previous day*, *tomorrow* to *next day* same way in above given sentence we will change it into that, Right? But the two "that"s in second option sound awkward.

Comment: ... Where does the disgust come from? I wouldn't think a scorpion was disgusting... it's dangerous... not gross.

Comment: What do you mean by "should be"? Should be according to the teacher who is going to grade this? Should be to make it sound okay for a book you're writing?

Comment: Grammatically, two consecutive ***that's*** is fine (apart from anything else, they fill completely unrelated syntactic roles, and if they *both* appear only the second will carry stress). But as you say, it's "awkward", so whereas you'll often *hear* it (because people can't always think as fast as they speak), you should probably avoid the repetition in most written contexts.

Comment: @J.R. I mean the best from the two given options.

Comment: Why only those two options? It's not clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @J.R. It's because the options come from an exam question. This question has the exam-question tag, but it's easy to miss. (I missed it.) I'll edit the question to clarify. Hopefully that will remove the basis for the downvote. :)

Comment: Please take note, it's very rare for a comma, period, exclamation point or question mark to have a space before it in English. I'm not sure it's common in any language, to be honest. I've edited this for you but keep it in mind for your future writing! :)

Comment: @BenK - I knew that, having seen the comment beneath your question. Still, I felt like it was important to leave comment the way I did, because too many questions get asked by people leaving out such critical information. I'm trying to spread the word as much as anything.

Comment: @J.R. Got it. That reminds me: I just started posting again after a long hiatus, and I'd forgotten all about linking to [this meta question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/6700). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Mother **warned** the children **not to go** near the scorpion.

In indirect discourse, you don't need to cover every word in the direct quotation. You can use a verb like **warned** to imply the tone of what was said. If the preceding context hasn't said that "it" is a scorpion, here are some graceful ways to introduce that fact in indirect discourse:

> Mother **told** the children **that it was a scorpion** and warned them not to go near it.
>
> Mother **pointed out that it was a scorpion** and warned the children not to go near it.
>
> Mother **warned** the children **that it was a scorpion** and told them not to go near it.

or even:

> Mother **exclaimed that it was a scorpion** and told the children not to go near it.

---

Oh, but this is from an exam question. This means that you must guess what the exam's author is trying to test you on. Here's my guess (which might be wrong): the author wants you to carry **it** over from the original quotation and into the indirect discourse:

> Mother said, "Oh! **It**'s a scorpion. Don't go near **it**, children."
>
> Mother exclaimed with disgust that **it** was a scorpion and told the children not to go near **it**.

The other alternative has **that** in place of **it**.

Saying **that** is still grammatically correct, but it's more emphatic. It's like pointing to the scorpion with your finger as you're speaking (or suggesting that Mother was doing that as she was speaking).

It's not a rule in English to change "yesterday" to "the previous day" in indirect discourse. That happens a lot, but only because the sentence with indirect discourse is usually said on a day other than the sentence that it describes. (You could ask a separate question about that.) You would change **it** to **that** only if, in the indirect statement, you wanted to clarify or change the emphasis of the original. There's no rule or custom suggesting that you should ordinarily do it.

---

Regarding your question about two consecutive **that**s, it does sound a little bit clumsy in English, but it's used quite often. It's used most often in speech, where rhythm makes it easier for a listener to follow: the stress goes on the second **that** and the syllable is usually lengthened a bit. It's formal enough for writing, though. Here's a typical example:

> His [last words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_words) were “Moby-Dick.” The friend who was with him at the time said **that that** was the movie that was playing on the TV in his hospital room, but I wonder if [he](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolf_Nureyev) was planning another ballet.
>
> <sup>Source: "[Wild Thing](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2007/10/08/wild-thing-2): Rudolf Nureyev, onstage and off", by Joan Acocella, *The New Yorker,* Oct. 8, 2007.</sup>

The first **that** introduces the subordinate clause. The second **that** refers to "[Moby-Dick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby-Dick)".

People used to put a comma after a **that** that introduced a subordinate clause, like the comma in your second option, but this went out of practice about a hundred years ago. You can still find it in books written in the 19th century, but on an exam, a choice with a comma in such a place will likely be marked wrong—unless the exam's author based the questions on hundred-year-old grammar books, which does sometimes happen.

Comment: Its a MCQ question with 4 options I have to choose the 'best' from them . Other two options were completely wrong so I didn't write them in post , its just these two options that i mentioned in post which are confusing me The answer posted by you isn't one of the available options to choose from.

Comment: @user212388 Oh…an exam question. :( OK, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @user212388 That sort of information is important to keep in the question... we need to know if you're writing this yourself or if it's from an exam because the context is important.

Comment: @Catija , Yeah sorry I missed to mention that in question.

Comment: That's what the [edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/130536/edit) button is for. Update your question; don't just leave critical information strewn about in comments.